# How to open a window when a window is already open in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, extjs4.1, extjs6

I want to open a new window but a window is already open. window is opening but at the back of that window which is already open??
i am new to extjs and using extjs 6.
model: true
bringToFront: true
 both are not working[image]

here in this image you see when i click on edit the small window is opening but at the back that window i just want to open it at the front of that window.
 hope you understand my problem now

Comment: Please post code and if possible a screenshot of the problem

Comment: hello i edited my question watch it now if you can help ;)  Flying Gambit

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Your code is either ExtJS 4.1, or ExtJS 6, but not both. Remove the wrong tag.

Answer (score 2):

The Method [show()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-show) ([toFront()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#method-toFront) also) will do the trick for you. Here a small example:

```
var a = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'a', 
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}).show();

var b = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'b', 
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}).show();

a.show(); // or a.toFront();
```

There is also a property [toFrontOnShow](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-toFrontOnShow), but it is true by default.

Comment: @Salman hassan OkZ, If this solves your question, please mark this as your accepted answer

Comment: its not working i dont think its just a varaiable problem

Comment: The example is working in ExtJS 6.0.2, which version do you have?

Comment: I am using extjs 6